# Get the name of a element (.Net MAUI / Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, maui, system.reflection

Hey i looking for a option to get the Element of a Control by finding the Parent.
Does this function exist in Xamarin.Forms / .Net MAUI?

**(Parents are GRID and Childrens are Frames)**

It needs to be find the current Parent and remove the children.
After that it should add the diced numbers + the old Parent (name is in numbers) and Add to the children to new calculated Parent.

Example Player1 is on F4 and diced 10. Player1 should be removed from F4 and replaced on F14.

This all can be done with long redundant code but in WinForms you can easily find out everything you need.
.Net MAUI doesn't look that familiar to me.

```
string field = "F";
int diced = 10; 
private void AddPlayer1(int diced)
{
    // What i want
    field = field + diced.ToString();
    field.Children.Add(player1)

    // what i have
    F1.Children.Add(player1);
}

Element parent;
private void RemovePlayer1()
{
    // What i want
    parent = GetParent(player1);
    parent.Children.Remove(player1);


    // what i have (long and redundant)
    if (player1.Parent == F0)
        F0.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F1)
        F1.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F2)
        F2.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F3)
        F3.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F4)
        F4.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F5)
        F5.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F6)
        F6.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F7)
        F7.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F8)
        F8.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F9)
        F9.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F10)
        F10.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F11)
        F11.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F12)
        F12.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F13)
        F13.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F14)
        F14.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F15)
        F15.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F16)
        F16.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F17)
        F17.Children.Remove(player1);
    else if (player1.Parent == F18)
        F18.Children.Remove(player1);
}
```

Comment: My feeling: Your are completely the wrong way with your coding style than MAUI wants you to be. A good exercise: Create your app so that it in theory could run without any GUI. Then you are on the right way.

Comment: It should be a Gameboard Game, so i should declare and initialize everything in C# instead of XAML ? ^^

Comment: Yes, I thought something like that. Create your app, but don't think about an UI. Maybe create the app as a console app first, just for practice. And if it works migrate it to MAUI. And at every step think about creating it in a way that has little changes when you will migrate.

Comment: Or maybe a bit more precise: A parent-children structure should have nothing to do with a GUI. It's just a data structure. And at the end (maybe) there is a GUI that displays your game. But it does nothing else. No logic, no data storage, no data structures, ... Just display.

Answer (score 3):

My Solution:

Here i can get the Parent via FindByName.

```
    //Declare
    Random dice = new Random();
    string field = "F";
    int current = 0;
    int diced;

    //Dice
    diced = dice.Next(1,7);  

    //FindByName
    Grid FRemove = FindByName(field + current.ToString()) as Grid; 
    Grid FAdd = FindByName(field + diced.ToString()) as Grid;

    //Remove and Add
    FRemove.Children.Remove(player1);
    FAdd.Children.Add(player1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If Parent is Grid and Children is frame then in this scenario you can get the children by specifying the row and column of Grid.

Sample Code:

```
var parent = grid.Children;
//loop through your rowNumber and columnNumber such as 1,1/1,2....
var children = parent .Children.Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == rowNumber && Grid.GetColumn(c)== columnNumber);
//Similarly you can find the children and replace by specifying the row and column
```